# Conversion of JSON to Presto based SQL Query

Tags: sql, node.js, json, amazon-web-services, presto

I am creating a web app in which there is an analytical dashboard that is allowed to generate a query. This query will be forward to backend server through an exposed API. The controller (written in Node.js) behind this API will execute this query on AWS Athena to fetch the required data.

Now the problem is that how should I send query to backend server. Should I use JSON format? Then at backend How should I convert JSON to SQL Query? Do I need to write custom solution or is there any supported library available?
Is there any better way of doing this?

I have tried some JavaScript libraries like JSON-SQL, JSON-SQL-Builder2 but these doesn't support the format of Query that will be executed by Athena. Athena uses Presto engine to run a query.

Comment: Inputs and expected outputs are always a helpful addition to a question about conversions. But, since your question lacks any attempt, no one here will be able to help you with specifics.

Answer (score 0):

Good evening,

If your problem is sending a query to the database from Node, then it seems like the [AWS SDK for JavaScript in Node.js](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/).

Your workflow will likely be something like:

1. [Start Query Execution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Athena.html#startQueryExecution-property)
2. [Get Query Execution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Athena.html#getQueryExecution-property)
3. [Get Data from S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property)